# Linq query to people whose last name starts with letter 'A'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a model class `Person` which has field: `public string LastName { get; set; }` . I want to browse table `Persons` in my `db` for all people whose first letter of last name is `A` OR `Ą` and group them by name.

I have a problem with a query. I don't know how to select all of these people and alternatively  I don't know how to select from 51st to 100th person

I tried this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
   var list =  from person in db.Persons where (person.LastName.StartsWith('A'+"") ||person.LastName.StartsWith('Ą'+"") ) HOW TO SELECT AND GROUP THEM HERE
   return View(list);//argument should be of type List<Person>    
}
```

**Question:** How to get all people whose name starts with 'A' or 'Ą' or people which are from 51st to 100th postiion in table?

---

**EDIT:**

Answer helped but I can't convert it into `List`

```
public ActionResult Index(/*char lastNameFirstLetter = 'A'*/) {      
        var queryResult =  db.Persons.Where(person => person.LastName.StartsWith("A"))
        .OrderBy(person => person.Id) // you need OrderBy before Skip
        .GroupBy(person => person.LastName);
        var list = queryResult.ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
```

when I go to the view `Index.cshtml` I get yellow screen of death:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,WebApplication2.Models.Person]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication2.Models.Person]'.
```

the model of Index is:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Person>
```

Comment: you probably want `OrderBy`, `Skip`, and `Take`.  They're used for paging

Comment: Change `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Person>` to `@model List<WebApplication2.Models.Person>`

Answer (score 6):

I think you want something like this:

```
db.Persons.Where(person => person.LastName.StartsWith("A"))
  .OrderBy(person => person.Id) // you need OrderBy before Skip
  .Skip(50)
  .Take(50)
  .GroupBy(person => person.Name);
```

Comment: No, no please very much no lambda expressions. I just was asking for linq query.

Comment: well this is a linq query

Comment: @Yoda, How do you do linq without lambdas? I mean, you could make your own functions and call them, but it's more effort.

Comment: How is called the style of query I posted in OP? Next time I will now how to ask better.

Comment: @Yoda, that's called "query" style. This is "extension method" style. You can't do `skip` and `take` in query style.

Comment: @gunr2171 That explains it all. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I also asked about letter `Ą` I know that `||` can be insterted but is there any way to force SQL think about letters like: `Ą` as `A`, `Ć` as `C`, `Ó` as `O`, `Ę` as `E` when quering?

Comment: @Yoda, That is a new question. Please post a new question for that. Keep posts to one question at a time.

Comment: Could you please have a glance at edit? My OP was in context of ASP .NET MVC action and I get an error saying that I passed list of elements of wrong type.

Comment: @Yoda you need to remove GroupBy then